# How to add a constant to a control system block diagram

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, block-diagram

I have an equation of the system as let's say \$v=fu+c\$. I have the block diagram as
[image]

Only problem is how do I get a Laplace domain transfer function out of this diagram for the output \$\large v\$ and input \$\large u\$. I could treat the constant \$\large c\$ like another input and the whole system as a MISO to get 2 transfer functions but that would mean in the transfer function of \$\Large\frac{v}{u}\$, the constant \$\large c\$ does not matter nor has any effect as it would not show up. Is it possible to get a SISO transfer function of a system with two inputs?

Comment: @Hearth: in this context, the OP means a Laplace-domain transfer function.  Adding a constant is a nonlinear operation (it's affine, but still nonlinear).  So -- how can that be, when Laplace-domain analysis doesn't admit to nonlinear analysis?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get a single-input, single-output transfer function of this system that takes both \$u\$ and \$c\$ into account.

Laplace-domain analysis only works for linear systems, i.e. ones that obey superposition.  Strictly speaking, adding an independent constant makes the system nonlinear (you can check me on that: \$y = a x\$ is linear, and obeys superposition, but \$y = a x + b\$ does *not*).  The resulting system is affine, which is the world's easiest nonlinearity to resolve, but it's still nonlinear.

You must do one of two things: do your linear analysis while ignoring \$c\$ then patch up the results, or treat the system as a multi-input, single-output system.

To "ignore" \$c\$, set \$c = 0\$, do your analysis, then add it back to the output.

There's a number of ways to treat the system as MISO.  The easiest is to find *two* transfer functions: \$\frac{V(s)}{U(s)}\$ and \$\frac{V(s)}{C(s)}\$.  Then -- because you've modeled a system that's linear but has two inputs -- you can use superposition to find \$v\$ by adding the system response to \$u\$ and the system response to \$c\$.

Alternately, you could model your system in state space, or you could model it with a vector-valued transfer function; i.e. $$H(s) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{V(s)}{U(s)} & \frac{V(s)}{C(s)}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ok, I get that I could get the value of \$v\$ but I need a transfer function at the end as I need to calculate the H infinity norm and response to step input among other things. I am using Matlab for calculating this stuff but the transfer function thing has got me pinned down.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with this new information, so that it is complete (this is a Stackexchange thing -- we're not like usual forums).  In anticipating of you editing your question, I've updated my answer.  The short answer -- no, you cannot have a SISO transfer function with two inputs, nor can you have _any_ Laplace-domain transfer function for a nonlinear system.  You _can_ model the system as a MISO system and use that in your analysis.